# Replace uppercase characters with lowercase+extra characters

Tags: python, regex, string, str-replace

I am trying to find all the uppercase letters in a string and replace it with the lowercase plus `underscore` character. AFAIK there is no standard string function to achieve this (?)

For e.g. if the input string is `'OneWorldIsNotEnoughToLive'` then the output string should be `'_one_world_is_not_enough_to_live'`

I am able to do it with the following piece of code:

```
# This finds all the uppercase occurrences and split into a list 
import re
split_caps = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', name)
fmt_name = ''
for w in split_caps:
    fmt_name += '_' + w # combine the entries with underscore
fmt_name = fmt_name.lower() # Now change to lowercase
print (fmt_name)
```

I think this is too much. First `re`, followed by list iteration and finally converting to lowercase. Maybe there is a simpler way to achieve this, more pythonic and 1-2 lines.

Please suggest better solutions. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Why don't you have a look at [the `str` methods](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). *"there is no standard string function"* - what were you expecting, `str.uppercase_to_lowercase_with_underscores`?

Comment: I am aware that SO is not a code writing service. Just wanted to see if there are better solutions, more pythonic and 1-2 lines.

Comment: If you want working code reviewed, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the link. I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com I will give it a look. By standard I meant replacing a string with some pattern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not a simple regex:

```
import re
re.sub('([A-Z]{1})', r'_\1','OneWorldIsNotEnoughToLive').lower()

# result '_one_world_is_not_enough_to_live'
```

Comment: This will replace consecutive uppercase characters with lowercase characters preceded by a single underscore. This should avoid it `([A-Z]{1})`

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
string1 = "OneWorldIsNotEnoughToLive"
list1 = list(string1)
new_list = []
for i in list1:
    if i.isupper():
        i = "_"+i.lower()
    new_list.append(i)
print ''.join(new_list)

Output: _one_world_is_not_enough_to_live
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string = input()

for letter in string:
    if letter.isupper():
        string = string.replace(letter, "_" + letter.lower())
print(string)
```